# Android 13 often doesn't change media notification cover

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession, android-13

I have discovered some bug (or not?).
I have radio app with detecting song and setting these songs' covers to the media player notification. I have noticed that the data in MediaStyle notifications are from metadata from mediasessioncompat. I set data when something change (new song/cover downloaded):

```
MediaMetadataCompat.Builder builder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, metadataTitle);
builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, name);
builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, metadataTitle);
builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, radioData.getId());
builder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, duration);
builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, songCover);
builder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, icon);
```

Everything works but when I load new cover (METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART) and want to change only cover it doesn't work. It worked on previous Android versions. My use-case:
Setting radio data -> getting sont data -> setting song data (title,artist), new notification -> loading cover -> setting downloaded cover (new notification) - and here image in notification doesn't change (but color overlay does). I need to change some title/artist data to make it change.
Is that normal behaviour?

Edit:
I have created a bug request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243778594

Comment: Hi. Have any solution for this?

Comment: It is Android 13 bug. I change some other data like title to make it update but it is very dirty solution.